# Periodically download attachments from mail box

Tags: cron, email, download

Is there a preferably CLI based program I can use to regularly (through cron for example) use to check a mailbox, and download the attachments into a folder?

I have a mailbox called photos@doamin.com, I would like to periodically poll the inbox for new emails via POP or IMAP, and grab the attachments to any new emails (they will be photos) and download them to a local folder.

What CLI email utils can do this?

Comment: I use fetchmail and maildrop as a cronjob, but it might not be what you want

Comment: The basic idea is to download the mails using `fetchmail` or similar, and then extract the attachments with [`munpack`](http://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/mpack/). (I won't develop on this, so I'll just leave this comment and no answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fetchmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetchmail) is the de facto standard program to retrieve mail over POP or IMAP automatically. You can inject email in the local email system for delivery, or have fetchmail invoke a mail delivery agent such as [procmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) or [maildrop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildrop) directly.

To extract and possibly strip the attachments, you can use any of the several MIME manipulation tools, such as [mpack](http://packages.debian.org/sid/mpack), [metamail](http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/unix/mail/metamail/).

Here's a simple example using procmail (`mda procmail` in `~/.fetchmailrc`) which saves image attachments and still delivers the mail normally — put this in your `~/.procmailrc`:

```
PHOTO_DROP_DIR=$HOME/photos/incoming
:0c
* ^To: photos@doamin.com
| munpack -q -C "$PHOTO_DROP_DIR"
```